# Dúvida ao projetar um banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, desempenho, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software

Qual a melhor forma de projetar um banco de dados para um sistema web, por exemplo, esse sistema é para médicos, e cada médico tem sua agenda, pacientes, caixa, etc. O que seria melhor:

1. Um único banco de dados onde os registros de todos os médicos são armazenados nas mesmas tabelas (tabela de agenda, pacientes, caixa); ou;
2. Cada médico ter seu banco de dados, e tudo ficaria separado, cada um com sua tabela de agenda, de pacientes, de caixa, etc;.

   Sei que existem pós e contras, eu acredito que a melhor forma seria a primeira, por questão de manutanção. Mas pensando no desempenho, e imaginando que numa tabela de agenda com todos os médicos fazendo CRUD na mesma tabela, como seria o desempenho disso?
   Eu gostaria de saber por argumentos qual a melhor forma projetar essa banco de dados. E o por que.

   Talvez seja uma dúvida bem simples para muitos, mas eu não tenho muita experiência nessa área.

Comment: Para optar pela forma 2 tem que ver a que taxa suas tabelas são populadas. A taxa não parece ser muito grande, o banco costuma ser capaz de lidar com tabelas da ordem de centenas de milhares ou mesmo milhões de registros sem maiores problemas (desde que o volume de dados trazido nas consultas não seja absurdo). Forma 1.

Comment: @Piovezan mesmo em bilhões você irá de 30 para 32 buscas, se muito. Na verdade o pior cenário, e muito raro, é ir de 1 para 3, porque triplica (mas triplicar em cima de tão pouca busca não importa), o que eu citei dá 5% de perda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em essência o desempenho não faz diferença, existirá alguma, mas não será significativa. E depende da carga.

O primeiro pode ter um problema mínimo de performance porque as árvores dos índices poderão ser mais profundas e pode ter 1 ou 2 níveis a mais para analisar antes de chegar no item desejado, mas isso costuma ser irrisório.

O segundo tende pôr mais informação na memória já que é tudo separado e não usar frequentemente, então o cache começa trabalhar contra e não a favor, e haverá perdas pontuais.

Qual é melhor você não saberá de antemão nem conhecendo seu cenário teórico, só o uso real indicará o que funciona melhor, e poderá mudar de acordo com um mudança de padrão, até testes podem falhar porque envolve muita variável, mas dificilmente verá grande diferença.

Faça de acordo com a real necessidade, de acordo com requisitos, e se preocupe menos com a arquitetura, só deixe fácil mudar se um dia precisar, mas não será por causa da performance. Se tiver problemas de performance é porque tem várias outras coisas muito mais erradas, por exemplo não ter índice onde precisa, ou fazer buscas sem necessidade.

Todos os médicos fazendo CRUD não fará cosquinha porque ela estará 99,99% do tempo com a tela parada sem operação alguma no banco de dados. E o que seria todos os médicos? Todos do Brasil ao mesmo tempo? Aí talvez seja um problema e precisará de uma engenharia pesada. Todos de uma clínica? Tem quase zero impacto. Será algo importante para um hospital? Melhor contratar um engenheiro experiente para cuidar disso.